# How can we consume KTable of Windowed<String> using spring cloud kafka streams?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

In an application# 1, I am creating a KTable -

```
KTable<Windowed<String>, GenericRecord> table = stream
        .groupByKey()
        .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(windowMs))
        .aggregate(new GenericRecord(schema),
                (key, old, new) -> ..,
                Materialized.<String, GenericRecord, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>>
                        as("window-store")
                        .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                        .withValueSerde(new GenericAvroSerde));
```

In another application#2, I am consuming this channel as

```
public void process(@Input(Channels.INPUT) KTable<Windowed<String>, GenericRecord> input) {
input
                .toStream((key, value) -> key.key())
                .foreach((key, value) -> {
                    LOGGER.info(value);
                });
}
```

In both the apps, default keySerde is String -

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.key.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.value.serde: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.GenericAvroSerde

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.application-id: demo-service
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination: demo-service-window-store-changelog
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.useNativeDecoding: true
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.headerMode: raw
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.input.consumer.keySerde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.input.consumer.valueSerde: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.GenericAvroSerde
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.input.consumer.materializedAs: window-store
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.input.consumer.application-id: ${random.int}
```

While consuming at application#2, I am getting exception as -

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Windowed
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamImpl$1.apply(KStreamImpl.java:152)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamImpl$1.apply(KStreamImpl.java:149)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMap$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMap.java:41)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.runAndMeasureLatency(ProcessorNode.java:244)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:133)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:143)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:126)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:90)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMapValues$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMapValues.java:41)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.runAndMeasureLatency(ProcessorNode.java:244)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:133)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:143)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:126)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:90)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.ForwardingCacheFlushListener.apply(ForwardingCacheFlushListener.java:42)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingKeyValueStore.putAndMaybeForward(CachingKeyValueStore.java:101)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingKeyValueStore.access$000(CachingKeyValueStore.java:38)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingKeyValueStore$1.apply(CachingKeyValueStore.java:83)
```

Looks like, I need to set WindowSerde of type String for key in application#2, not sure how I can set this ?

Comment: Can you describe how you send data from the first application into the Kafka topic? It will be better if you can show the code for that.

Comment: I have it in the comment above - KTable<Windowed<String>, GenericRecord>

Comment: My question was more about how you send the data to the topic `input-ktable` from application #1. Its not clear how are doing that.

Comment: I meant, as part of KTable<Windowed<String>, GenericRecord>, it sends the data to changelog topic with the name <application-id>-window-store-changelog. I am not making call .toStream() to send the same data to any other topic. On the consumer side, on second app, we consume data from the same topic. So the destination bind to Channels.INPUT is the same changelog topic. I got the same logic working without Windowed but facing cast exception on using Windowed.

Comment: What is this config then?`spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination: input-ktable`.

Comment: sorry, for the confusion. I have updated the configuration above. Also, is it possible to give keySerde configuration in yaml of type Windowed<String>

Comment: Can you see if this makes a difference? `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.input.consumer.keySerde: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.WindowedSerdes$TimeWindowedSerde`

Comment: Did that make a difference?

Comment: I see an exception - ```Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
 at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.loadClass(Utils.java:333)
 at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.newInstance(Utils.java:322)
 at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.TimeWindowedSerializer.configure(TimeWindowedSerializer.java:53)
 at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$WrapperSerde.configure(Serdes.java:40)```